# How to install application as windows service using NSIS script

Tags: windows-services, nsis

How to install application as windows service using NSIS script?

I used this command in the script `Exec '"sc.exe"` but after installation i couldn't find any service in windows services related to it so help me thanks.

Comment: Could you post an excerpt of the failing script to show how the parameters of the `Exec` statement? Do you have any warning in the `makensis` output?

Comment: ExecWait '"C:\Windows\System32\sc.EXE" "Test Service"'
Exec $PROGRAMFILES\Example1\xxxx.EXE

Comment: Do not confound the service name and the display name: `Test Service` as service name is not correct due to the space

Comment: Please post the *exact* syntax you use in your `sc` command. To register a service, you need `sc create ...`, `sc service name` is not a working command

Comment: i cant(dono)able to update my script its saying error seki. you understood my problem rite?? you can send me example script it will help me i hope thanks

Comment: You seem to have a problem for configuring a new service. For now, I am unsure if you have a problem inside your NSIS script, or with the `sc` command that you use. Try the `sc` command with correct parameters directly in a command prompt. Does it configure the service, or do you have an error message (if so, what message)?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe that the NSIS [Simple Service plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin) can help you. The syntax is as simple as

```
SimpleSC::InstallService "MyService" "My Service Display Name" "16" "2" "C:\MyPath\MyService.exe" "" "" ""
Pop $0 ; returns an errorcode (<>0) otherwise success (0)
```

Here the example install the service as ServiceType own process + StartType automatic + NoDependencies + Logon as System Account.
Please refer to the accompanying help for the meaning of the magic numbers.

The wiki shows the [5 other methods](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_do_I_start/stop/create/remove/check_a_service) to handle services with NSIS.

Comment: i cant get it Seki... after the installation my service should be in the windows service. i can able to stop or start by using that entry please help me clearly thanks... what does it means "C:\MyPath\MyService.exe"

Comment: I have added the SimpleSC.dll into the NSIS folder and to which place i want to add this code in my script ???SimpleSC::InstallService "MyService" "My Service Display Name" "16" "2" "C:\MyPath\MyService.exe" "" "" ""
Pop $0 ; returns an errorcode (<>0) otherwise success (0)

Comment: @SujeethDamodharan Be aware that there's a function to look up error codes for you. You also need to make sure the user ahs the "Log on as a service" right - which is another function. Read the documentation for example of both

Comment: I trying with this example , and i have probleme Plugin not found, cannot call SimpleSC::StartService,sorry i dont very googd in english

Comment: Note: **The SImple Service plugin does not work with Unicode NSIS**

Answer (score 6):

There are [multiple plugins](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/How_do_I_start/stop/create/remove/check_a_service) out there as stated on NSIS website

For me it seemed to be unnecessary complicated, so I ended up using `sc` tool directly. A command is quite simple:

```
!define appName "theApp.exe"
!define displayName "My Awesome Service"
!define serviceName "MyAwesomeService"

ExecWait 'sc create ${serviceName} error= "severe" displayname= "${displayName}" type= "own" start= "auto" binpath= "$INSTDIR\${appName}"'
```

A full list of `sc create` arguments available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create)

Answer (score -1):

Below is the scripts which first stops service, uninstalls previous version, remove form registry and then installs fresh copy.

```
Section "Mobile Interface" 

  SimpleSC::StopService "MobileInterface" "1" "60"
  SimpleSC::RemoveService "MobileInterface"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKLM "MobileInterface"
  RMDIR /r "$INSTDIR\MobileInterface\"

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\MobileInterface"
   # define what to install and place it in the output path
 File "D:\NCS.Sentinel\NCS.Sentinel.MobileWebSvc\bin\Release\"

 SimpleSC::InstallService "MobileInterface" "MobileInterface" "16" "2" "$INSTDIR\MobileInterface\NCS.Sentinel.MobileWebSvc.exe" "" "" ""
 Pop $0 ; returns an errorcode (<>0) otherwise success (0)
 SimpleSC::StartService "MobileInterface" "" "100"

#WriteRegStr HKLM "D:\NCS.Sentinel\NCS.Sentinel.MobileWebSvc\bin\Release\NCS.Sentinel.MobileWebSvc.exe" 

  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

  ; Store installation folder
  ;WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Mobile Interface" "" $INSTDIR



SectionEnd
```