# Need a (script)procedure to install an application as windows service using NSIS script

Tags: windows-services, nsis

I having 3 .exe files (1.exe, 2.exe and 3.exe) and 2 .msi files (1.msi and 2.msi). Using NSIS script I created a Package.
By installing that package this service should be in Windows services window. 
But I do not know the script to register this service.
Help me thanks.

Actually I used `Exec '"C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe" "MY Service Name"'` 
Even though I couldn’t find my service in this path Start Menu -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.
Help me...

Comment: Do not ask the same question multiple times. You can edit [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786875/how-to-install-application-as-windows-service-using-nsis-script) to add additional information, like the `exec` command shown here.

Comment: BTW, when posting commands, copy / paste the *exact* syntax, as bare `sc "my service name"` is not a correct syntax

Comment: okay seki.. then the correct syntax???

Comment: If I understand what you write, your nsis installer is deploying several .exe and other setups, and one of them must be configured as a service, and your `sc` call fails for some reason. *Please show what you tried* (the whole `Exec` line from the nsis script), so we can try to correct it. It might also be another problem, but for now we cannot tell.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [NsSCM](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsSCM_plug-in) or any other service plug-in from the [wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aPlugins)?

Comment: Added specific .dll into NSIS folder. but i dont know how to add the service install commands into my script idleberg.. i am new in NSIS world help me thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use SERVICE plugin ( ServiceLib ) from here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Service_Lib

Does the job well! ;)